# PHP Error "Undefined Index" After Successful Charge Transaction

Tags: stripe, charge

Ran into PHP errors when running a test transaction using Charge on my local setup. Everything worked fine, technically speaking: the test transaction went through on Stripe; the member was moved to the right member group (i.e., the correct Charge action was taken); etc.

However, instead of being directed to the success page, the page gets stuck on the ACT URL and shows the PHP errors shown in this screenshot: http://cl.ly/image/1T333W0D2d21

Any ideas? Need this working pretty quickly here (of course). We're using EE 2.8.1 & Charge 1.8.6.

Comment: Just curious, Angie...did you manage to get this question answered or find the cause of the issue?

Comment: I did. Joel Bradbury sent me an early release version. I think it's now fixed in 1.8.7 though (looks like it just got released today).